# When does Broadcast Receiver start?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-manifest

I'm new to android and trying to build a simple app which needs to listen for incoming sms. I know that I need to use the BroadcastReceiver class and I also know how to make my own broadcast receiver. But how do I start it? Does it start automatically if I set the code for it in the manifest? The app just has the Main activity, do I need to somehow add a broadcast receiver in the onCreate of this activity? I searched for an answer, but it's still not clear to me. I know it's not nice to ask, but it would be great if you can share some sample code. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you declare the receiver within your AndroidManifest.xml, then you shouldn't need to do anything more. When a broadcast gets sent, the Android system will look through all installed apps and notify each app that has declared the appropriate Receiver in its manifest, starting the app in the process if necessary. For most cases, such as SMS, that is how you want to declare receivers, because most broadcasts are sent with the intent that you want to open your app when its not currently running to react to the broadcast.

Alternatively, you may declare the broadcast within a running activity, which may be useful if you want the broadcast to directly update the UI in your running app.

[BroadcastReceiver Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html)

Comment: thanks a lot! No the broadcast does not need to change anything in the UI, just do some stuff in background.. Really appreciate your help :)